# How to apply vertical alignment to child components in an Angular 10 custom component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am creating my own Angular component (something akin to a 'card'), where the custom components will be something like:

```
<app-my-card>
   <app-my-card-header>
   </app-my-card-header>
   <app-my-card-body>
   </app-my-card-body>
   <app-my-card-footer>
   </app-my-card-footer>
<app-my-card>
```

The app-my-card component will have 'height' and 'width' attributes.
How can I supply styling so that the 'app-my-card-footer' component is always aligned vertically at the bottom of the 'app-my-card' display area?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

Inside the top level component use multiple filtered 'ng-content' tags, like:

```
<div class="my-card-content smart-stack-layout vertical space-between">
    <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%">
      <ng-content select="app-my-card-header"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
      <ng-content select="app-my-card-body"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div style="height: auto; width: 100%">
      <ng-content select="app-my-card-footer"></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
```